# css selector for the dynamic element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I have to update the Quantity of the product whose element id and name changes with product.
eg for Product 1
id="quantity_11046"
Product 2 
id="quantity_15678"

I am using css as :

```
WebElement Qty=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains(“quantity_1”)");
```

and

```
WebElement Qty=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""input[id$='quantity_1']");
```

But getting error unable to find the element.

```
<div>
<input type="number" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" min="1" max="999" ng-model="qty" ng-blur="blurred()" ng-change="changed()" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-readonly="readonly" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-maxlength" name="quantity_11046" id="quantity_11046">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebElement Qty=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id^='quantity_']"));
```

worked Thanks